# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: error on Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new on docker and I'm trying to run this docker-compose file.
I keep getting the same error-

> failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount39063561/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

This is my directory tree:

[image]

This is my docker-compose file:

```
   version: '3'
    services:                                        
      nginx:                                          
        image: nginx
        ports:
          - 80:80
        environment:
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
        volumes:
          - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro     
        depends_on:                                    
          - app1
          - app2
          - app3
    
      app1:
        build:
          context: ./app1
        volumes:
          - ./app1_logs:/app/logs                     
      
      app2:
        build:
          context: ./app2
        volumes:
          - ./app2_logs:/app/logs
    
      app3:
        build:
          context: ./app3
        volumes:
          - ./app3_logs:/app/logs
      
      db: 
        image: mongo
        environment:
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
        volumes:
          - ./db_data:/data/db
          - ./db_logs:/var/log/mongodb
    
    volumes:
      app1_logs:
      app2_logs:
      app3_logs:
      db_data:
      db_logs:
```

My Dockerfile_app3 (they are all the same except "app3.py") :

```
FROM python:3.9                 

WORKDIR /app                     

COPY . /app                       

RUN pip install requirements.txt  

EXPOSE 80                        

CMD ["python", "app3.py"]
```

And on requirement.txt:

```
flask
```

Comment: Rename each dockerfile to `Dockerfile` or specify the file name in the build.dockerfile attribute in each app entry in docker compose.

Comment: I've specified the file name and it worked. Thank you!